# Building a discord antispam bot and getting errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, discord, discord.py

Very new to discord bots and python in general and building an antispam bot, here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import time

b = commands.Bot(command_prefix='not a bot')
b.remove_command("help")

@b.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is Ready')

authors = {}
authors1 = []
@b.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    global authors
    global authors1
    author_id = ctx.author.id
    for author2 in authors1:
        if author_id == author2:
            authors[author_id] += 1
        else:
            authors[author_id] = 1
            authors1.append(author_id)
    stop = False
    timer = 5
    while stop == False:
        if timer > 0:
            time.sleep(0.985)
            timer -= 1
            if authors[author_id] > 5:
                await ctx.send("Stop Spamming")
        else:
            timer = 5
            authors[author_id] = 0

b.run('stack overflow')
```

Basically on every message it gets every users discord id and then assigns a value to it, default is 1 since the user just sent a message, where the while loop starts is a timer, every 5 seconds it resets and if the user who's sent the message has sent 5 messages, it tells them to stop spamming, I don't know why I'm getting errors, also since I'm new to python is I could make any code simpler it would be much appreciated if you could let me know.

Here's the error I keep getting

```
Bot is Ready
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\12488\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_even
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\12488\Downloads\Bot\antispam.py", line 31, in on_message
    if authors[author_id] > 5:
KeyError: 234295307759108106
```

Comment: Please post the error as text.   From what I grasp, the authors dictionary doesn't have that author_id and seeing that you've initialized ```authors = {}```, I suspect you didn't check if ```author_id``` is in ```authors```.  When the code starts,  ```authors``` is ```{}``` and ```authors1``` is ```[]```.  So it skips down to the condition and errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things:

1. The error message is occurring because you are referencing a author_id which isn't set
2. Your variable names are extremely confusing, this makes it difficult to understand what you were going for.
3. I think there is an issue with your logic. I am not sure why there is a sleep loop at the bottom.

Anyway, I think the following code will do what you'd like it to.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import datetime
import time

b = commands.Bot(command_prefix='not a bot')
b.remove_command("help")

time_window_milliseconds = 5000
max_msg_per_window = 5
author_msg_times = {}
# Struct:
# {
#    "<author_id>": ["<msg_time>", "<msg_time>", ...],
#    "<author_id>": ["<msg_time>"],
# }


@b.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is Ready')


@b.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    global author_msg_counts

    author_id = ctx.author.id
    # Get current epoch time in milliseconds
    curr_time = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000

    # Make empty list for author id, if it does not exist
    if not author_msg_times.get(author_id, False):
        author_msg_times[author_id] = []

    # Append the time of this message to the users list of message times
    author_msg_times[author_id].append(curr_time)

    # Find the beginning of our time window.
    expr_time = curr_time - time_window_milliseconds

    # Find message times which occurred before the start of our window
    expired_msgs = [
        msg_time for msg_time in author_msg_times[author_id]
        if msg_time < expr_time
    ]

    # Remove all the expired messages times from our list
    for msg_time in expired_msgs:
        author_msg_times[author_id].remove(msg_time)
    # ^ note: we probably need to use a mutex here. Multiple threads
    # might be trying to update this at the same time. Not sure though.

    if len(author_msg_times[author_id]) > max_msg_per_window:
        await ctx.send("Stop Spamming")

b.run('stack overflow')
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I'm not sure how the author id isn't set as I set it to ctx.author.id and sorry for the variable names, I will try to make them less confusing next time, and to explain the sleep loop, I was trying to make a resetting timer that resets the messages count for the amount of messages sent by the author, thanks for the code, I'm pretty sure I understand it, it gives me an error though telling me ctx has no send object on line 56, also really sorry for wasting your time, but what I'm not to sure what a mutex is or how it relates.

Comment: Haha, no problem, I figured that the sleep loop was some kind of expiration attempt. First, about the error with `ctx.send()` ... I read the docs and it looks like when you use `on_message(ctx)` it should probably be `on_message(msg)` (because a message object is passed in ... I usually use `ctx` as short for `context`, but this doesn't matter) anyway, since it is a message object, you want to do something like `ctx.author.send("message")` or, if you rename the `ctx` var, then `msg.author.send("stop spamming")` ... I would read the docs.

Comment: About the Mutex ... So, in the code above, when a message occurs, the code is executed. Imagine that two message come in within a fraction of a second; the code both reads and modifies the global variable `author_msg_times`, and since there are two instances running "simultaneously," there might be issues where the variable is updated out of order and you aren't getting a clear picture of how many messages are outstanding. I am uncertain if this is an issue or not. However, the way to resolve this potential issue is to lock and unlock the global variable to make sure that it is consistent.